# Signal-r installation issue

Tags: javascript, signalr

I'm trying to install SIgnal-r library into my project using :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

provided here:http://signalr.net/ but i am having this error 
[image]

Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR 2.0 doesn't work on .NET 4.0 projects. You need to install SignalR 1.1.3. See http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr for more details.